# Sumar meses, horas, minutos y segundos a una fecha tipo timestamp en base a la fecha actual y un campo duración de mi bd

Tags: php, timestamp

necesito sumarle meses a la fecha actual con horas, minutos y segundos mediante un campo de mi base de datos llamado duración y que el resultado sea una fecha sumada con el campo duración. El campo duración contiene un número entero.

Este es el error que me devuelve
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (now + "6" month) at position 4 (+): Unexpected character in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php(26): DateTime->__construct('now + "6" month') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php on line 26

Este es mi código con la función con la que intento hacer la suma de las fechas y la consulta para insertar.

```
    $fecha = new DateTime(); 
    $fecha_venc = new DateTime('now + "'.$duracion.'" month'); 
    $conexion->query("insert into pagos
    (nombre,documento,banco,numero_cuenta,referencia,fecha_pago,fecha_vencimiento,monto,
    id_usuario,id_plan,id_estatus) values
    ( 
    '".$_POST['nombre']." ".$_POST['apellido']."',
     ".$_POST['documento'].",
    '".$_POST['banco']."',
    ".$_POST['numero_cuenta'].",
    ".$_POST['referencia'].",
    '{$fecha->format('Ymd')}'
    '{$fecha_venc->format('Ymd')}',
    ".$_POST['monto'].",
    $id,
    $idp,
    '1'
    
  )
    ")or die ($conexion->error);
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: probá agregarle con `$fecha->modify('+6 months');` sin comillas ni espacios

Comment: Hola Malbarez, gracias por responder, necesito que se sume con la variable $duracion porque esa variable viene cargada de la base datos y depende de la opción que elija el usuario si le pongo el número 6 directamente siempre va a sumar 6 meses y no debería ser así.

Comment: probá reemplazar el 6 con un `intval( $duracion )` el [`$fecha->modify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.modify.php) es lo que te permite sumar sin crear un intervalo o transformar un `strtotime`

Comment: No sé si es a esto que te refieres que haga                                                      
$fecha = new DateTime(); 
$fecha_venc = $fecha->modify(intval($duracion));                                        Warning: DateTime::modify(): Failed to parse time string (6) at position 0 (6): Unexpected character in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php on line 26

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lacorotera\pagar.php on line 37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando [DateTime->modify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.modify.php) podes especificar la suma.

```php
<?php
$duracion = '6';

$fecha = new DateTime();
$fecha_venc = new DateTime();
$fecha_venc->modify( sprintf( '%+d months', intval( $duracion ) ) );
// alternativa sin filtrado 
// $fecha_venc->modify( '+' . intval( $duracion ) . ' months' );


var_dump( $fecha, $fecha_venc );
```

resultado:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-10-30 17:29:47.953242"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(10) "US/Pacific"
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-04-30 17:29:47.953268"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(10) "US/Pacific"
}
```

Comment: Gracias, ¿cuándo colocas alternativa sin filtrado a qué te refieres?

Comment: filtrado refiere a que el `sprintf` filtra el numero como `d`ecimal y si es positivo le agrega un `+` y si es negativo le agrega un `-` el `intval` se asegura que sea un valor numérico entero ( o cero en caso de falla o que le pases un string que no representa un número )

Comment: Muchas gracias, me suma las fechas, pero me las guarda en mi bd sin hora, sin minutos y sin segundos

Comment: es por el `->format('Ymd')` ( Año mes día ) fijate en el manual las [diferentes opciones de formato](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) que hay ( a la versión español del manual le falta esa parte )

Comment: Si ya lo había resuelto colocándole al formato His muchas gracias, saludos.